# Create custom field for shipping method in Drupal Commerce 2

Tags: drupal-8

I'm trying to add a new field called Opening Hours for commerce_shipping_method bundle. I'm having hard time finding examples how to do this and those I tried didn't really work for me. In fact, not even adding a simple numeric field worked for me.

I have 2 YML files in  a custom module where I define the testing numeric field.

#### custom_module.field_instance.yml

```yaml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.commerce_shipping_method.field_opening_hours_x
id: commerce_shipping_method.commerce_shipping_method.field_opening_hours_x
field_name: field_opening_hours_x
entity_type: commerce_shipping_method
bundle: commerce_shipping_method
label: 'Test Numeric Field'
description: 'A test field'
required: false
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings: {  }
third_party_settings: {  }
deleted: false
```

#### custom_module.field_storage.yml

```yaml
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - commerce_shipping
id: commerce_shipping_method.field_opening_hours_x
field_name: field_opening_hours_x
entity_type: commerce_shipping_method
type: decimal
module: number
settings:
  precision: 2
locked: false
cardinality: 1
translatable: true
indexes: {  }
persist_with_no_fields: true
custom_storage: false
```

When I install this module and go to edit my shipping method ( /admin/commerce/shipping-methods/manage/2?destination=/admin/commerce/shipping-methods ), the extra field is not present.

Any help or pointers to the right docs on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help from the [slack commerce community](https://app.slack.com/client/T06GX3JTS/C1TLCCF9B/thread/C1TLCCF9B-1689921887.589389) and reviewing a [Drupal article on field definitions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/defining-and-using-content-entity-field-definitions), I came up with the following resolution:

### my_commerce.module

Here is where the definition that's shown on form page goes. It didn't work if I simply used it in the update hook (second file below), so I had to duplicate the definition in my .module file as well.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info().
 */
function my_commerce_entity_base_field_info( EntityTypeInterface $entity_type ) {
  $fields = array();

  // add opening hours text area field to commerce shipping methods
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'commerce_shipping_method') {
    $fields['opening_hours'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create( 'text_long' )
      ->setLabel( t( 'Opening Hours' ) )
      ->setDescription( t( 'You can provide opening hours to physical pickup/payments points.' ) )
      ->setRevisionable(true )
      ->setTranslatable( true )
      ->setSetting( 'target_type', 'commerce_shipping_method' )
      ->setSetting( 'handler', 'default' )
      ->setSetting( 'handler', 'default' )
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'text_textarea',
        'settings' => array(
          'display_label' => true,
        ),
      ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'text_long',
        'weight' => 0,
      ])
      ->setCardinality( 1 )
      ->setDisplayConfigurable( 'form', true );
  }

  return $fields;
}
```

### my_commerce.install

While the .module file will show the Opening Hours textarea on the opening hours form, this part handles saving the value for that field into the database.

```
/**
 * Add opening hours field to all shipping methods.
 */
function my_commerce_update_9006() {
  $field_storage_definition = BaseFieldDefinition::create( 'text_long' )
    ->setLabel( t( 'Opening Hours' ) )
    ->setDescription( t( 'You can provide opening hours to physical pickup/payments points.' ) )
    ->setRevisionable(true )
    ->setTranslatable( true )
    ->setSetting( 'target_type', 'commerce_shipping_method' )
    ->setSetting( 'handler', 'default' )
    ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
      'type' => 'text_textarea',
      'settings' => array(
        'display_label' => true,
      ),
    ))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'type' => 'text_long',
        'weight' => 0,
      ])
    ->setCardinality( 1 )
    ->setDisplayConfigurable( 'form', true );

  \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
    ->installFieldStorageDefinition('opening_hours', 'commerce_shipping_method', 'commerce_shipping_method', $field_storage_definition);
}
```